# Find all real function $f(x)$ satisfy the functional equation

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions, functional-equations, functional-calculus

Find all real function $f(x)$ satisfy this functional equation $|f(x) - f(y) | \leq  |\sin(x-y) -x+y| $ for all $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$?

**My ideas:** I showed that the constant functions are a class of such functions. However, I have not  known all solutions. Would you please give some comments (or hints) for this problems?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Have you found any other functions for this besides constants?

Comment: Of course, we can see some properties. For example, $$|f(x) - f(0)| \leq |sin (x) - x|, \forall x \in \mathbb{R} .$$ Or, with x near y, $$|f(x) - f(y)| \leq |(x-y)^3| |\dfrac{1}{3!}  - \dfrac{(x-y)^2}{5!} + \ldots |$$

Comment: @coffeemath However, I have not yet get a full solution.

Comment: ToThichToan--- I was just asking for any particular nonconstant solution. I don't see one in your comments above.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint 1:** Notice that
\begin{align}
\sin z = z-\frac{z^3}{3!}+\frac{z^5}{5!}+\ldots.
\end{align}

**Hint 2:** For what functions do we have
\begin{align}
|f(x)-f(y)|\le C|x-y|^3?
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you @Jacky Chong. Could you write the solutions after the second hints?

Comment: @ToThichToan I think I will just leave it like this. This is a good problem to work out the details for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $|f(x) - f(y) | \leq  |\sin (x-y) -x+y|$ for all real $x,y.$ For $y$ held constant, put $x=y+h$ where $h \neq 0.$ Then the inequality, after division by $|h|,$ becomes
$|\frac{f(y+h)-f(y)}{h}| \leq | \frac{\sin h}{h}-1|.$ Now let $h \to 0$ through nonzero values from either side, then the right side goes to $0$ from which follows $f'(y)=0$ for any real $y.$ Thus only constants can satisfy your inequality.